# Change page by button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

In my xaml file i have

```
 <Button 
    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
 </Button>

<Frame
    Grid.Column="1"
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
     Content="{Binding CurrentPage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Frame>
```

My viewmodel class:

```
        private readonly LoginPageView _loginPage;  // Page i want to use
        private readonly StartPageView _startPage;
        private Page _currentPage;

        public StartWindowViewModel(LoginPageView loginPage, StartPageView startPage)
        {
            _loginPage = loginPage;
            _startPage = startPage;
            CurrentPage = _startPage;
            LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenLoginPage, _ => true);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Page CurrentPage                                  // I'm binding my frame to this property
        {
            get => _currentPage;
            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

        private void OpenLoginPage(object parameter)
        {
            CurrentPage = _loginPage;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
```

I want to change page displayed in frame by clicking a button. I'm not sure if i should user Frame for this, but it seems okay. The problem that i'm not updating page,

Answer (score 0):

My solution not seems to be best possible:

```
<Frame
    Grid.Column="1"
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
    Source="{Binding PageName}">
</Frame>

public string PageName
{
    get => _pageName + ".xaml";
    set
    {
        _pageName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I don't actualy like this way of solving, so i would be happy if somebody would give a better approach.